# Problem to combine 2 queries to get single set of results

Tags: sql-server, nested

I have written two queries for SQL Server, one to provide "Revenue Total" and one to provide "Carrier Total".  I have confirmed that both work properly.  Now, I'm trying to pull all of this data into on set of results with the following query.

```
select 
    a.ctripnumber, 'Revenue Total', 'Carrier Total' 
from 
    (
        (select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total' 
         from 
             (select 
                  r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
              from  
                  revenuedtl r 
              where 
                  r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
                  --and r.ctripnumber = '324198'
              group by 
                  r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod) r
         group by 
             r.ctripnumber),
        (select p.ctripnumber, sum(Carrier_Subtotal) as 'Carrier Total' 
         from 
             (select 
                  p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod, sum(p.curevenue) as Carrier_Subtotal 
              from 
                  payrolldtl p 
              where 
                  p.cmethod in (select distinct p.cmethod from payrolldtl p) 
                  --and p.ctripnumber = '324198'
              group by 
                  p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod) p
         group by p.ctripnumber)) a
where 
    p.ctripnumber = r.ctripnumber
group by 
    a.ctripnumber
```

However, I'm getting these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The ',' seems that it should be correct, as I am trying to get results from three columns.  I checked the ')' and don't see any orphaned ones.

I've tried the following using inner join, but I get some different errors

```
select 
    r.ctripnumber, 'Revenue Total', 'Carrier Total'
    (select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total' 
     from 
         (select r.ctripnumber,r.cmethod,sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
          from revenuedtl r 
          where r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
          group by r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod) r
     group by r.ctripnumber)
inner join
    (select p.ctripnumber,sum(Carrier_Subtotal) as 'Carrier Total' 
     from 
         (select p.ctripnumber,p.cmethod,sum(p.curevenue) as Carrier_Subtotal 
          from payrolldtl p 
          where p.cmethod in (select distinct p.cmethod from payrolldtl p) 
          group by p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod) p
     group by p.ctripnumber) on r.ctripnumber = p.ctripnumber
```

The errors that I get this time are:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'
>
> Clarification

There are two queries that are working well, one that pulls trip numbers and revenue, and another that pulls trip numbers and carrier cost.

> Query 1

```
select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total' 
         from 
             (select r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
              from revenuedtl r 
              where r.cmethod in 
                  (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
              group by r.ctripnumber,r.cmethod) r
         group by r.ctripnumber
```

> Partial results are:

```
ctripnumber Revenue Total
160837  682.00
232813  1151.75
163973  335.00
249132  3024.00
```

> Query 2

```
select p.ctripnumber, sum(Carrier_Subtotal) as 'Carrier Total' 
         from 
             (select p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod, sum(p.curevenue) as Carrier_Subtotal 
              from payrolldtl p 
              where p.cmethod in 
                  (select distinct p.cmethod from payrolldtl p) 
         group by p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod) p
    group by p.ctripnumber
```

> Partial Results are:

```
ctripnumber Carrier Total
206266  48.00
111099  225.00
107283  206.25
6558    250.00
```

> Now that I have these queries, I want to combine the results, so I
>   wrote the following:

```
select 
    a.ctripnumber, 'Revenue Total', 'Carrier Total' 
from 
    (
        (select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as 'Revenue Total' 
         from 
             (select r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod, sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
              from revenuedtl r 
              where r.cmethod in 
                  (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
              group by r.ctripnumber,r.cmethod) r
         group by r.ctripnumber),
        (select p.ctripnumber, sum(Carrier_Subtotal) as 'Carrier Total' 
         from 
             (select p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod, sum(p.curevenue) as Carrier_Subtotal 
              from payrolldtl p 
              where p.cmethod in 
                  (select distinct p.cmethod from payrolldtl p) 
         group by p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod) p
    group by p.ctripnumber)
) a
where p.ctripnumber = r.ctripnumber
group by a.ctripnumber
```

> I am getting the following errors:
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: there are so many syntax error. Not knowing what your query is doing, not really sure how to correct your query

Comment: Just a tip from the side lines: I would try to **AVOID** using the same query/table alias over and over again; it seems like all your aliases are `p` or `r` - something across multiple levels - this doesn't only confuse the reader - it might also confuse SQL Server's query processor at some point. An alias should be **unique** within a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using spaces inside column names, but does this work for you?

```
select 
    tRev.ctripnumber, "Revenue Total", "Carrier Total"
FROM
(select r.ctripnumber, sum(Revenue_Subtotal) as "Revenue Total" 
 from 
     (select r.ctripnumber,r.cmethod,sum(r.curevenue) as Revenue_Subtotal
      from revenuedtl r 
      where r.cmethod in (select distinct r.cmethod from revenuedtl r)
      group by r.ctripnumber, r.cmethod) r
 group by r.ctripnumber) tRev
inner join
(select p.ctripnumber,sum(Carrier_Subtotal) as "Carrier Total" 
 from 
     (select p.ctripnumber,p.cmethod,sum(p.curevenue) as Carrier_Subtotal 
      from payrolldtl p 
      where p.cmethod in (select distinct p.cmethod from payrolldtl p) 
      group by p.ctripnumber, p.cmethod) p
 group by p.ctripnumber) tCar on tRev.ctripnumber = tCar.ctripnumber
```

Comment: Thanks Richard! This has been a pain in my side for a whole day.  I can see that I was close, but need to be more careful with my use of aliases which was pointed out by @marc_s. Have a great day!